# Unable to access global array in AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, scope

I'm trying to access a global array inside the $.getJSON callback. For some reason I can access the array for actually *calling the ajax request*, but it is undefined within the callback.

**JS**

```
var toprint  = [
    {name: "Name", 
     year: "2014", 
     call: "http://api.call.com"},
     // etc.....
]


for(var i = 0; i < toprint.length; i++){


$.getJSON( toprint[i].call, function( data) { // toprint[i].call accessed fine
            // some code...

            // toprint[i] undefined below
            jsonPrint = "<div class='col'><h3>" + toprint[i].name + "</h3>" + toprint[i].year + "<ul>";
            // some code...
        });

}
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError:  toprint[i] is undefined
```

Which is weird, because according to other SO questions I've read I'm supposed to be able to access global variables inside AJAX callbacks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the global array.  Your problem is your loop variable i.  At the time that the callback is called i could potentially be out of bounds. In your case it is out of bounds. What you can do to fix issue is create a new variable local to your loop. `var currIdx = i;` and the use that variable inside of your callback function like `toprint[currIdx].name`. Unfortunately I have no way to test this at the moment, but I believe that if you do it this way the value of the variable `currIdx` will be bound to your callback function. If this doesn't work then try `var currRec = toprint[i];` and use `currRec.name` within your callback function.  I actually prefer the second method.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < toprint.length; i++){
    $.getJSON( toprint[i].call, function( data) { // toprint[i].call accessed fine
        // The for loop is done and value of i === toprint.length
        // by the time this is executed
    });
}
```

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous and your `for` loop completes before the callback is triggered. When the loop completes, the value of `i` will be `toprint.length`. So if `toprint` had 3 items, the value of `i` will be 3 by the time the callback executes.

The callback attempts to read `toprint[3]` which does not exist as `toprint` contains just 3 items (`[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]`). Since it does not exists `toprint[3]` returns `undefined` and trying to access `.name` from `undefined` gives you the mentioned type error.